# Convert function from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am new to oracle sql. My question is, how do we convert following to SQL Server syntax(TSQL)?

oracle:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table TABLE'
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement:

```
EXECUTE ('truncate table TABLE')
```

Which `TABLE` is your table name.